# Get name of parent object in array loop

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, vue.js

I have the following array of objects:

```
payload: [
    {name: one},
    {name: two,
    values: {name: five}
    },
    {name: three},
    {name: four}
]
```

I loop through this in a recursive way, because this depth of the data can change anytime. So `name: five` can have there own values again.
Now when I loop through the values of an object, I want the name of the parent object. So for `name: five` I want to get `two` in a method.

Is there any way to obtain this name?

I use vue.js a a Javascript library.

This is my loop:

```
<ul>
    <div class="row">
        <li v-if="value.name" class="col-md-3 indent" @click="toggle">
            {{value.name}}:
        </li>
        <li v-else class="col-md-3 indent" @click="toggle">
            {{value.type}}:
        </li>
    </div>
    <div v-show="open" v-if="isValue">
        <codeblock-value
            v-for="value in value.values"
            :value="value">
        </codeblock-value>
    </div>
</ul>
```

And I render this loop like this in my parent file:

```
<div class="row" v-for="value in payload.values">
    <codeblock-value
        :value="value">
    </codeblock-value>
</div>
```

Keep in mind that there can be multiple objects with values.

Comment: please add your code.

Comment: The Vue website has an example of how to build a tree view: https://vuejs.org/v2/examples/tree-view.html

Comment: Yes I know, this is the base of my code! But now, as this Tree View as the base code, as I click on `wat` or `hello`, I want to log `child-folder`.

Answer (score 0):

```
function recurse(parentName, obj) {
    console.log("Parent name is: " + parentName);
    console.log("Obj name is: " + obj.name);

    if(obj.values) {
       recurse(obj.name, obj.values);
    }
}

recurse(payload[1]);
```

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the question, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion. Please also try not to crowd your code with explanatory comments, this reduces the readability of both the code and the explanations!

Answer (score 0):

If you can change your payload structure slightly it would make life a bit easier.

**[JSFIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/kz3240LL/)**

**JS**

```
var payload = {
    name: "payload",
    values: [{
        name: "one"
    }, {
        name: "two",
        values: [{
            name: "five"
        }]
    }, {
        name: "three"
    }, {
        name: "four"
    }]
};

function dig(parent) {
    console.log(parent.name);
    if (parent.hasOwnProperty('values') && Array.isArray(parent.values)) {
        for(var x = 0, len = parent.values.length; x < len; x++){
            dig(parent.values[x]);
        }
    }
}

dig(payload);
```

**UPDATE FOR VUE.JS**
Again, changing the data structure allows you to access the parent. In this example, i dynamically generate the test data so that each child node references its parent (I threw in some randomness to generate folders or not).

**[JSFIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/3p0j5sgy/87/)**

**Data generation JS**

```
var data = {
    name: 'My Tree',
    children: []
}
var maxDepth = 4;
function createChild(parent, currentDepth){
    var childrenValues = ['hello', 'wat', 'test'];
    var createChildFolderChance = 0.5;
    for(var x = 0, len = childrenValues.length; x < len; x++){
        var child = {
            name: childrenValues[x],
            parent: parent
        }
        if(Math.random() < createChildFolderChance && currentDepth < maxDepth){
            child.children = [];
            currentDepth++;
            createChild(child, currentDepth)
        }
        parent.children.push(child);
    }
}

createChild(data, 0);
```

**Updated Vue.JS click code**

```
function() {
    if (this.isFolder) {
        this.open = !this.open
    }else{
        var firstSiblingWithChildren;
        // cycle through current node's parent's children (ie. siblings) and return the name of the first node that has children
        for(var x = 0, len = this.model.parent.children.length; x < len; x++){
            if(this.model.parent.children[x].hasOwnProperty('children') && Array.isArray(this.model.parent.children[x].children)){
                firstSiblingWithChildren = this.model.parent.children[x].name;
                break;
            }
        }
        console.log(firstSiblingWithChildren);
    }
},
```

Comment: Maybe you could have a look at this [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/yyx990803/3p0j5sgy/?utm_source=website&utm_medium=embed&utm_campaign=3p0j5sgy). This is the Vue.JS Tree View. I used this as my base code. Now I want, when I click on `wat` or `hello`, to log `child-folder`.

Comment: @InbarAzulay, updated https://jsfiddle.net/3p0j5sgy/87/ and in my answer